# Drawing circle using coordinates from individual array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Currently I'm developing an Android app which draws a point on the coordinates input by the user. I'm rather new to java so please assist me. Cheers.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    float[] manualpointx ={100,200,300,400,500,600};
    float[] manualpointy ={120,300,400,560,600,500};
      for (int i = 0;i<100;i=i+1)
      {
          canvas.drawCircle(manualpointx[i], manualpointy[i], 5, paint);
          invalidate();
      }
}
```

The problem happens when `canvas.drawcircle` is called and the app crashes.

Comment: Could you detail exactly what is your intention and why you wrote that, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you refer to `manualpointx[i]` and `manualpointy[i]` for i from 0 to 99 and the fact is that  **they are not defined for i greater than 5**. You try to refer to a cell of an array that is out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: @RonTan Could you tell us what you wanted to do so that we can help you?